# Need a regular expression to capture url path

Tags: php, regex

I am using PHP, and I have been trying to create a regular expression pattern to capture part  of URL path, but to no avail.

The possible URL path could be any of these:

- "product/zzz"
- "yyyyyyyy/product/zzz"
- "xxxxx/yyyyyyyy/product/zzz"
- "xxxxx/yyyyyyyy/.../product/zzz" (... means other possible words)

what I need to capture is the part before "product".

for the first case, the result should be an empty string.
for the rest, they are "yyyyyyyy", "xxxxx/yyyyyyyy" and "xxxxx/yyyyyyyy/..."

Can anyone here give me hint? thanks!

PS.
It looks like the part I wanted is a repetition of same pattern "xxxx/". but I am not good at using group of regex.

Update:

I probably found a solution, by capturing pattern "xxx/" with zero or more repetitions: "([^/]+/)*"

so the full regex should be "(([^/]+/)*)product/([^/]+)"

@SERPRO: it passed the test in your "Live RegExp".
Hope it is helpful.

Comment: **[What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)**

Comment: I seem to have found a solution and want to share it to all you guys. see the last part of my orginal post

Answer (score 1):

I would use `parse_url()`:

```
$path = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH);
// Deal with $path to figure out what's after '/product/'
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

`^(.*[^/]|)/*product/[^/]+/*$`

It will also allow an arbitrary number of slashes at the end of the path.
The part inside parentheses is your result.

Comment: thanks for your quick answer. but I need to deal with any number of "xxx/" pattern, not just 3.

Comment: your pattern matches "xxx/product/abc", but not "xxx/yyy/product/abc", nor "xxx/yyy/zzz/product/abc".

Comment: Even easier :-) I changed the regex

Comment: It's returning `/` after the match the OP was looking for.. should be `xx/yyy` not `xx/yyy/`

Comment: Now it doesn't match `product/zzz`

Comment: @lilalinux mine too, if you think it doesn't, please provide example or information :)

Comment: Word boundary is empty in the POSIX column http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#POSIX_Basic_Regular_Expressions

Comment: greatly appreciate your helps. still working on it, but your info is very useful.

Comment: @lilalinux update yourself, "The POSIX functions are deprecated." http://php.net/manual/en/book.regex.php

Comment: Maybe for PHP. I just said mine will work with any interpreter ;-)

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```
#(.*?)/?product.*\b#
```

You can see an example of result strings here:

http://xrg.es/#5awa10

Comment: What about foo/bar/product/meh/product/zzz ;-)

Comment: Yeah, but uses too much unnecessary voodoo :-)

Comment: I don't know what do you mean by "unnecessary voodoo" but the regexp does work and it's easy to read.

Comment: @SERPRO can you tell me what the ending "\b" means?

Comment: Isn't the \b an extended regex?

Comment: @dikko2000 it's a word boundary in xrg.es you can see on the top right a "Help" link.. it explains all

Comment: @lilalinux no it's not.. and it's only for multiple line examples.. it can be replaced with `\z` for what the OP is looking for (a single string)

Comment: But it still matches foo/bar instead of foo/bar/product/meh

Comment: who said it has to match the latest match of product? for what I understand it needs to match what is before product. if OP needs to match the latest, should be clarified in the question.

Comment: I'm pretty sure he wants to match everything before product/zzz ;-)

Comment: greatly appreciate your helps. still working on it, but your info is very useful.